# Drag and Drop Jquery function not working in site

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, drag-and-drop

I'm having a problem getting my code to work when it's incororated into a live site.  The fiddle works just fine, but when I include the identical code in a webpage, I can't get the function to load/work at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Drag and Drop Assignment</title>
<!doctype html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style1.css"/>

<style>

.drop{
float: left;
width: 350px;
height: 400px;
border: 3px solid blue;
background-image: url("http://debsiepalmer.com/images/tardis 2.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:  cover;
}
#right{float: left;
width: 350px;
height: 400px;
border: 3px solid red;
}

</style>

<script src="draganddrop.js" ></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js" ></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$ (init);

function image(id, image1) {
this.id = id;
this.image1 = image1;
}

$('#deal').click(function () {dealAll(
dealCard(randomCard()));
});

 $(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "#left"});
});

function init() {
 $('.drop').droppable( {
 drop: handleDropEvent
  } ); 
$("img").draggable();
}

// global variables
var cardsInDeck = new Array();
var numberOfCardsInDeck = 15;
cardsInDeck[0] = "Ace";
cardsInDeck[1] = "Grace";
cardsInDeck[2] = "Susan";
cardsInDeck[3] = "Ian";
cardsInDeck[4] = "Barbara";
cardsInDeck[5] = "Brigadier";
cardsInDeck[6] = "Romana I";
cardsInDeck[7] = "K9";
cardsInDeck[8] = "Tegan";
cardsInDeck[9] = "Jamie";
cardsInDeck[10] = "Sarah Jane";
cardsInDeck[11] = "Jo";
cardsInDeck[12] = "Romana II";
cardsInDeck[13] = "Yates";
cardsInDeck[14] = "Leela";
var cardsDealt = new Array();

function dealAll(){
var z=0;
 for (z=0;z<5;z++) {
   cardsDealt[z] = new Image(z,dealCard(randomCard()));
}
}

function dealCard(i) {
if (numberOfCardsInDeck == 0) return false;
var $img = new Image();
$img.src = "images/Companions/" + cardsInDeck[i] + ".jpg";
// Here I set the ID of the object
$img.id=cardsInDeck[i];
$img.class='drag';
document.body.appendChild($img);
$('#'+$img.id).draggable();
removeCard(i);
return $img;
}
// deal randomly - works

function randomCard() {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfCardsInDeck);  
}

function removeCard(c)
{

for (j=c; j <= numberOfCardsInDeck - 2; j++)
{
    cardsInDeck[j] = cardsInDeck[j+1];
}
numberOfCardsInDeck--;
numberOfCardsInDeck--;
numberOfCardsInDeck--;
}
function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
alert("Fantastic!  You chose " + ui.draggable.attr("id") + " to be your companion.");
// Here I want the id of the dropped object
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" div style="width:750px; margin:0 auto;">
<div id="page_content" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 750px" class="auto-style8">

<!--Begin Assignment 10 --->
<div id="left" class="drop">
<img id="tardis" ></img>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Get Companions" id="deal" />
<div id="content" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 750px">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's supposed to generate 5 images, one of which can be selected to be dropped onto the target and generate an alert with the id of the image being dropped.  Like I said, it works just fine in the fiddle - and the code is identical on the web page, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/reaglin/FUvT8/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ordered some code...and for me it worked

```
// global variables
var cardsInDeck = [],
    numberOfCardsInDeck = 5;
cardsInDeck[0] = "Ace";
cardsInDeck[1] = "Grace";
cardsInDeck[2] = "Susan";
cardsInDeck[3] = "Ian";
cardsInDeck[4] = "Barbara";
cardsInDeck[5] = "Brigadier";
cardsInDeck[6] = "Romana I";
cardsInDeck[7] = "K9";
cardsInDeck[8] = "Tegan";
cardsInDeck[9] = "Jamie";
cardsInDeck[10] = "Sarah Jane";
cardsInDeck[11] = "Jo";
cardsInDeck[12] = "Romana II";
cardsInDeck[13] = "Yates";
cardsInDeck[14] = "Leela";


//load "init" when document it's ready
$(document).on('ready',init);

function init() { 
  $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "#left"});
  $('.drop').droppable( {drop: handleDropEvent}); 
}

$('#deal').click(function () {
    dealAll();
});
$('#reset-pictures').click(function(){
    $('img.drag').remove();
    numberOfCardsInDeck = 5;
});
// deal 5 cards at once - works
function dealAll(){
    // 5 cards max, no repeat cards
    while(numberOfCardsInDeck){
        var rand = randomCard();
        dealCard(rand);
    }

}

//deal cards - works
function dealCard(i) {
    //create id, remove space id
    var id_picture = (cardsInDeck[i] +'-'+i).replace(/\s/g, '');
    //validate not exist image
    if (!!$('img#'+id_picture).length) {
        return;
     }

    var $img = $('<img/>', { src : "http://debsiepalmer.com/images/companions/" + cardsInDeck[i] + ".jpg", id : id_picture, class : 'drag', 'data-info': cardsInDeck[i]
                          })
    $('body').append($img);
    $('img.drag').draggable();
    numberOfCardsInDeck--;

}
// deal randomly - works
function randomCard() {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * cardsInDeck.length);  
}


// this is what to do when card drops in tardis
function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
    alert(ui.draggable.attr("data-info"));
}
```

**DEMO**

[JSFinddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johan_16/WnFkH/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's still not working when I transfer the code to the site.  I pulled the libraries too, but no go.  Have I missed something really fundamental about moving script from a fiddle?

Comment: mmm, and inside the console will not throw any error message?, such that jQuery is not defined?

Comment: Nope,  not a clue as to what's actually wrong with it.  The only errors Firebug picked up are with the background, which works just fine.  Nothing to indicate a code problem.  It looks like (at least to my novice eyes) that the code is OK, the libraries are OK, the HTML is OK... It works in a fiddle, but pressing the button on a live page does nothing.  I can see that it's actually "pressing" the button, but it's not doing anything after that.

Comment: still not working.  Does anything look out of place?  I'm pretty new at this still.  Maybe there's one of those "it's Javascript magic" rules that I'm not aware of?

Comment: but, you copied the code you shared and you still did not work?, why do not you share the code that you have?

Comment: Can you try to add a trigger event on your button like a click function and add an alert message to find out if it is a syntax error? if the alert message does not come up, it could be a JavaScript conflict that is preventing your code to run? Then you could try to add jQuery no conflicts. Also, how many JavaScript libraries do you have on your page?

Comment: The code above is the code from the site, which is identical to the fiddle, which I also shared.  I've only been doing this (web designing) for a couple weeks.  I don't know enough about the tricks of the trade to understand why something like this would happen.  It doesn't make sense that it would work in the fiddle but the identical code doesn't work when it's live.

Comment: copy the code from "view source" on the next page, try view-source:http://fiddle.jshell.net/johan_16/FUvT8/11/show/light/

Comment: Holy cow!  It works!  Could you please explain how you fixed it and why that worked?  I'd really love to be able to put this in the "lessons learned" column.

Comment: did it again the code (check the format above), in an orderly so that you can understand. Guess what was missing was the document ready for that not walked the code when transcribe from Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking to JQuery correctly in the live version? Sometimes when moving from a development area to a live system the references mess up, you can find out if a reference is working or not by viewing the source code and entering in the link into the URL.

Comment: I've run into that problem before using fiddles, so I don't use any of the built in library-pulling tools there.  Instead, I include the exact libraries I need in the HTML section of the fiddle. I've found that makes it easier to move the script to a site when I get it right in the fiddle.  Unfortunately, that's not helping in this case.

Comment: I'm pretty new to javascript/jquery/web designing, so I can't say for sure if it's the right library, but it works in the fiddle, so I would think so.  How do I double-check that?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you fix it: Take all the javascript (from $ (init) to the alert()) and place it at the bottom of the loaded page, inside the body, after all the elements.  This ensures that the javascript knows what named elements you are talking about.

I would like to emphasise that this is not a tip for writing good javascript. The problem arises because it's bad javascript to begin with. Well written pages do not rely on the position of the code within the page, rather the opposite in fact.

Postscript: I literally did the following: I came here after googling "drag and drop"; I didn't fully read the actual question; I went to the jfiddle; I copied all the code for my own purposes; I couldn't get it to work; I fixed it (just trial and error really); I fixed the bug which is still present even on the jfiddle page; and then I came back here to find out what the original query had been!

The other bug is the fact that you can't drag the images of "Romana I", "Romana II" and "Sarah Jane". As the code makes the array values the id of the image elements, maybe others can instantly spot what causes that problem.